# JAVA HSSF read if ( String == String )

Tags: java, if-statement, hssf

I've been having this problem..
I read with HSSF xls cell (which value is lets say "turbox" value this way:

```
 String hssfstanskup = sheet.getRow(p).getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
```

then, I create a row in my JTablel like this:

```
 model.addRow(new Object[] { hssfstanskup } );
```

but if I create if statement like this:

```
 if((String) tprojekty.getValueAt(0,1) == "xxx"){
```

it doesnot work...

extra info: tprojekty = new JTable(model);
can anyone help me with this?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Did you try searching anywhere? String comparison requires you to use `equals` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you have to use the `.equals()` instead of `==`

```
if((String) tprojekty.getValueAt(0,1).equals("xxx")) {
```

Comment: thx Simon, sry for mistake in `equals`

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare strings in java you use the `.equals()` method instead of `==`.

Please try:

`if((String) tprojekty.getValueAt(0,1).equals("xxx"))`

which should solve your problem! The answer for this could have been found though with a simple Google search, or checking previous posts on StackOverflow! So in future take a look around for a solution before you post a question.

Comment: There is no need to cast returned value from `getValueAt` to String since every Object has `equals` method and thanks to polymorphism if returned object will be String code of `equals` will be taken from String class.